# Como obter nomes de coluna de uma tabela no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tabela `Idiomas`:

[image: estrutura da tabela]

Como selecionar os nomes das colunas desta tabela?

O resultado seria:

```
"IDIdioma", "Sigla"e "IDioma".
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Outra forma de obter os nomes das colunas de alguma tabela é consulta [sys.columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) usando a função [object_id()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx) que recebe o nome da tabela/view e retorna seu id interno.

**Isso funciona a partir do SQL Server 2008**

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = object_id('nome_tabela')
```

**Referência:** [How do you return the column names from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/600446/1342547)

Answer (score 15):

Faça um select em [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/183/informationschemacolumns/) pedindo a coluna `COLUMN_NAME`. Em `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` você tem informações sobre todas as colunas para todas as tabelas de um esquema de banco de dados.

## **Query:**

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NomedaTabela'
```

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa668c/1)

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma *procedure* pronta para fazer isto e é a forma mais simples de fazer, dá um resultado bem completo e embora possa não dar o resultado do jeito que deseja, por isso teste todas as opções constantes nesta página e escolha a que entrega o melhor para você.

```
exec sp_columns nome_da_tabela
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Procedure/ListTables.sql).

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para ver outros qualificadores e filtrar o que deseja.