# Como selecionar dados de uma coluna como colunas em SQL?

Tags: sql

É possível fazer uma consulta (**SELECT**) de dados retornados de uma coluna como **colunas**?

> select questores from tabela;

```
|   coluna    | → coluna
|-------------|
|    dado1    | → dados retornados da consulta
|    dado2    |                                                     
|    dado3    |
```

**Ex:** Essa linha abaixo seriam dados retornados de uma consulta de uma coluna:

Como eu conseguiria retornar os **dados** como **colunas** desta forma ↓

```
|dado1| dado2 | dado3|
----------------------
```

A ideia é retornar os dados dessa **coluna** como colunas e posteriormente fazer um atribuir dados para essas colunas que foram geradas pela consulta representadas como dados. No final ficaria algo assim e exporta-los pra uma planilha nesse formato:

```
 |dado1 | dado2  | dado3 | → colunas
 ------------------------
 |valor1| valor1 | valor1| → dados de alguma outra consulta 
 |valor2| valor2 | valor2|
 |valor3| valor3 | valor3|
```

Comment: Você quer selecionar a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como obter nomes de coluna de uma tabela no SQL Server?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187368/como-obter-nomes-de-coluna-de-uma-tabela-no-sql-server)

Comment: Boa Noite Brendow Adriel! Não tem como fazer isso diretamente com a consulta SQL. Para colocar os dados da consulta como colunas, você precisa fazer a consulta normal e trata-la um font-end

Comment: Brendow, é necessário que você utilize uma linguagem de programação para montar um array com os valores dessa consulta e printe esses valores em uma tabela front-end.

Comment: pesquise sobre `pivot` e isso depende muito de qual banco de dados está usando. Talvez uma forma mais fácil seria montar a query com vários sub-selects em tempo de execução. De qualquer forma, a questão não traz detalhes suficientes para elaborar uma resposta

Comment: Quero obter os valores de uma coluna selecionada como colunas.

Comment: @BrendowAdriel Evite alterar tão expressivamente o teor da sua pergunta, isso causa muita confusão e dificulta a obtenção de uma resposta mais precisa.

Comment: @BrunoMaciel, é possível sim, mas depende.

Comment: Qual banco de dados usa (SGDB)? Os dados são fixos ou dinâmicos? Já sabe como fazer a parte da exportação para Excel? Como?

Comment: No momento estou usando o MySQL. Dessa tabela em específico são dados físicos, é uma tabela de perguntas. Exportar para xsl ou csv não é problema, problema é a selecionar os dados nesse formato na consulta do banco.

Answer (score 1):

Em `Postgres` essa informação pode ser obtida a partir do [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/information-schema.html), de uma `VIEW` chamada [`columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/infoschema-columns.html).

Por exemplo, considere a tabela `tb_foobar`:

```
CREATE TABLE public.tb_foobar
(
  id INTEGER,
  name TEXT,
  moment DATE,
  flag BOOLEAN
);
```

Consultando todas as colunas da tabela:

```
SELECT
  column_name,
  data_type
FROM
  information_schema.columns
WHERE
  table_schema = 'public' AND
  table_name = 'tb_foobar';
```

Saída:

```
| column_name | data_type |
|-------------|-----------|
|          id |   integer |
|        name |      text |
|      moment |      date |
|        flag |   boolean |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/686b1/1

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que sua estrutura e os seus dados sejam algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_foobar
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  nome TEXT
);


INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 1, 'JESUS');
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 2, 'MARIA');
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 3, 'JOSE');
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 4, 'MADALENA');
INSERT INTO tb_foobar ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 5, 'JOAO');
```

Em `Postgres`, você pode usar a função de agregação [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html) para resolver o seu problema, ao invés de se criar uma coluna para cada registro da tabela, você pode criar uma coluna do tipo `array`, veja só:

```
SELECT array_agg( nome ) FROM tb_foobar;
```

Saída:

```
|                      array_agg |
|--------------------------------|
| JESUS,MARIA,JOSE,MADALENA,JOAO |
```

Você também pode usar a função `string_agg()` para gerar uma `string` com o separador da sua preferencia, por exemplo:

```
SELECT string_agg( nome, ';' ) FROM tb_foobar;
```

Saída:

```
|                     string_agg |
|--------------------------------|
| JESUS;MARIA;JOSE;MADALENA;JOAO |
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2aa66/7

Comment: 2 respostas para a mesma pergunta?

Comment: @Don'tPanic A pergunta sofreu edições "pesadas", preferi não mudar a resposta e inclui uma nova.